# The Erdős-Szekeres problem on points in convex position

Tags: computational-geometry, ramsey-theory, polygons, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

The Erdős-Szekeres problem on points in convex position and its proof using Ramsey theorem are well know. The problem goes like this:

For every natural number $k$ there exists a number $n(k)$ such that any $n(k)$-point set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ in general position contains a $k$-point convex independent subset.

My question is, how to prove the $d$-dimensional version of the problem?

For every natural number $k$ there exists a number $n_d(k)$ such that any $n_d(k)$-point set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ in general position contains a $k$-point convex independent subset.

The solution will probably use Ramsey theorem, but I don't know how.

Comment: What is a convex polygon in $\mathbb R^3$? Do you mean polyhedron?

Comment: Yes, I mean polyhedron. I restated the problems, now they should be more clear.

Comment: Can't you use linear projections to reduce the $d$-dimensional problem to several $2$-dimensional problems? For example in dimension 3 use the plans $XY, YZ$ and $ZX$. I haven't checked if this actually works.

Comment: I think orthogonal projection on a suitable hyperplane might work, but I don't know which one it is. After projecting, the points should remain in general position.

Comment: What is $n_1(3)$?

Answer (score 0):

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending_problem) on the Happy endings problem states:

"It is straightforward to show that, in higher-dimensional Euclidean spaces, sufficiently large sets of points will have a subset of k points that forms the vertices of a convex polytope, for any k greater than the dimension: this follows immediately from existence of convex k-gons in sufficiently large planar point sets, by projecting the higher-dimensional point set into an arbitrary two-dimensional subspace."